# Why is the following statement returning true?

Tags: java, graph, boolean, breadth-first-search

I'm attempting to write an implementation of Breadth-First Search in Java (not complete) but I am running into a problem when I try to iterate through all of the adjacent vertices to the starting vertex.

The program is iterating through all of the adjacent vertices, but when it reaches the if statement that checks to see if the TargetVertex has been visited it always returns true instead of false and therefore never runs the code inside the brackets.

I'm not sure why this is occurring because in the Vertex class I have initialized the value of visited to false for all new vertices. Does anyone see an error that I have made or know why this might be occurring? I've looked at all of the other methods/classes and none of them at any point change the value of "visited". Any help would be appreciated!!

```
public void doBFS(String s){

    //Create a queue
    Queue<Vertex> q = new LinkedList<Vertex>();

    //Create an arraylist to keep track of visited vertices
    ArrayList<String> visited = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Retrieve the starting vertex u, using the string name entered
    Vertex u = vertices.get(s);

   //Enqueue the starting node and add it to the visited set
   visited.add(u.name);
   u.visited = true;
   u.distance = 0;
   q.add(u);


 while (! q.isEmpty() ) {

   Vertex current = q.remove();

       for (Edge e : current.getEdges()) {
          //HERE IS THE PROBLEM. It always says it's true.
        if(e.targetVertex.visited = false) {

            visited.add(e.targetVertex.name);
            q.add(e.targetVertex);
            e.targetVertex.visited=true;        
        } 

        current = e.targetVertex;  
   }

}
```

}

The beginning of my Vertex class :

```
 public class Vertex {
   public String name;
   private List<Edge> adjacent;
   public int posX = 0;
   public int posY = 0;
   public boolean visited = false;
   public double distance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

   /**
   * Construct a new vertex containing an adjacency list.
   * 
   * @param vertexName
   *          a unique identifier for this vertex.
   * @param x
   *          the x coordinate for this vertex
   * @param y
   *          the y coordinate for this vertex
   */
  public Vertex(String vertexName, int x, int y) {
    name = vertexName;
    adjacent = new LinkedList<Edge>();
    posX = x;
    posY = y;
    distance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; 
    visited = false;
  }
```

Comment: `e.targetVertex.visited == false` ?

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot for not noticing that. Thank you!

Comment: or maybe a bit more readable `if (!e.targetVertex.visited)`

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Did it warn you that something was hinky in that condition? Did you ignore it? :)

Comment: I'm coding in VIM, I'm new to Java so I probably should use eclipse or something with more assistance in catching silly errors like that.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(e.targetVertex.visited = false) {
```

...is an assignment. Use

```
    if(e.targetVertex.visited == false) {
```

...or just

```
if(!e.targetVertex.visited) {
```

Comment: epic.....always like this...haha